# How do I initialize the state of a digital filter in Direct Form II?

Tags: filters, digital-filters

Suppose I have a digital filter implemented in Direct Form II. How do I initialize the state of the filter as if the input $x[n]$ had a fixed value $x_0$ for all $n<0$?

[image: Direct Form II Filter Topology]

Comment: normally we initialize states to zero, which corresponds to your input signal, $x[n]$ being prepended with an infinite number of samples that have zero value.

Comment: solve this equation $$w[-1] = (-a_1) w[-1] + (-a_2) w[-1] + x_0$$ for $w[-1]$.

Comment: I had asked a similar question: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/50992/how-would-i-calculate-the-state-variables-of-digital-biquad-filter-direct-form a while back. I had never thought much of filter initialization until I had to implement a 0.01Hz low-pass filter.

Answer (score 1):

The difference equations for this filter are:

```
y[n] = b0 w[n] + b1 w[n-1] + b2 w[n-2]
w[n] =    x[n] - a1 w[n-1] - a2 w[n-2]
```

To achieve steady-state, `w[n] == w[n-1] == w[n-2]`. Call this value `w`. Solving the second difference equation, we find `w = x/(1 + a1 + a2)`, where x is the steady-state input value.

Comment: you should swap the order of the two difference equations.  `w[n]` is calculated first.

Comment: BTW, i hope you're not using a DF2 filter with fixed-point arithmetic.  DF2 and fixed-point don't like each other if the filter gets resonant.